# How do I evaluate a nested match in an assumption that depends on a sumbool, given a witness to that sumbool in another assumption in Coq?

Tags: coq

I have a proof state similar to what is shown below (I've simplified it some to focus on the essence of the problem I'm having).  I'm almost certain that a contradiction exists in my assumptions.  However, assumption H consists of a nested match that depends on the result of the expression "eq_nat_dec n n'".  (I arrived at the left-hand-side of H by simplifying another function that is in terms of eq_nat_dec).

The *good* news is that i have an assumption (n0) that ensures that the "right" branch of the inner-most match should fire, which also ensures that the "inright" branch of the outer match should fire, resulting in the value "bad" ("good" and "bad" are two constructors of the same Inductive type, thus an assumption of good = bad would provide the necessary contradiction).

The *bad* news is that I don't know how to "inform" the inner match in assumption H about the assumption n0.  I've tried using subst, and inversion on H, but the nested matches remain.

In conclusion:  How do I force H to take the right branches of its matches using the information in n0?

```
  n, n' : nat
  H : 
    match
      match eq_nat_dec n n' with
      | left _ => inleft _
      | right _ => inright _
      end
    with
    | inleft _ => _
    | inright _ => bad
    end = good
  n0 : n <> n'
  ============================
  False
```

Answer (score 2):

The only solution I know is to destruct `eq_nat_dec n n'` and proves that the `left` branch is contradictory because of `n <> n'`. It would give something like:

```
destruct (eq_nat_dec n n'); [contradiction | discriminate].
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, as the previous answer said, destruct + congruence will work fine.

You could try to introduce a lemma:

```
Lemma eqn_rwN {x y : nat} (h : x <> y) : Nat.eq_dec x y = right h.
Proof.
destruct (Nat.eq_dec _ _); try congruence.
apply f_equal.
(* Use Eqdep_dec.eq_proofs_unicity? *)
Admitted.
```

so that you could rewrite the comparison, as this unicity of identity proofs should be provable given that nat has decidable equality:

```
Lemma u2
      (n n' : nat)
      (H : match (match Nat.eq_dec n n' with
                 | left  x => inleft x
                 | right y => inright y
                 end)
           with
           | inleft  x => true
           | inright _ => false
           end = true)
      (hnn : n <> n') : False.
Proof. rewrite (eqn_rwN hnn) in H. congruence. Qed.
```

Other Coq libraries such as mathcomp take a different approach and put equality in `bool`, thus you can directly rewrite:

```
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool eqtype ssrnat.

Lemma u3 (n n' : nat)
      (H : (if n == n' then true else false) = true)
      (hnn : n != n') : False.
Proof. by rewrite (negbTE hnn) in H. Qed.
```

IMVHO this turns out to be more convenient if you are verifying algorithms.